# How to make a c++ program and will use the command line input and ls in that directory?

Tags: c++, shell, command-line

My system is Ubuntu 20.04. Suppose I am in `project` directory and this directory contains these folders/files: `test`, `hello.txt`. I wrote the following program:-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    const char* command = "ls" + argv[1];
    system(command);
    return 0;
}
```

And then I will `test` as first argument of the program while running it. I expected it will print all files and folders in `test` folder. But it gave me an error.
Can someone tell me, what is the error and how to fix it?

Comment: `"ls" + argv[1]` is not how `char *` strings are done

Comment: You can't do this `"ls" + argv[1];` with c-strings. If you were using std::string you can do that.

Comment: "it gave me an error": show some sense. Tell us the error that it gave you. Word for word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you do in your code is not correct, You add two pointers, and the result you will clearly not be what you expect. Use [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).
So your code will look like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if(argc < 2)
    { 
        cerr << "missing cli argument\n";
        return -1;
    }
    auto command = std::string("ls ") + std::string(argv[1]);
    system(command.data());
    return 0;
}
```

Usually using the `system` function is a bad practice, so in your case I would rather use the functionality that performs your task: [display all files in folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612097/how-can-i-get-the-list-of-files-in-a-directory-using-c-or-c). Together with your code, it will look like this:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if(argc < 2)
    { 
        std::cerr << "missing cli argument\n";
        return -1;
    }
    std::string path = argv[1];
    for (const auto & entry : fs::directory_iterator(path))
        std::cout << entry.path() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does this data do in system? When I directly put command, it says system function can't work with string? How can this data method make it works correctly? Even I also tried to convert string to char*, but it said we can't convert string to char*.

Comment: There is documentation of string::data() here: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data)

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use `using namespace std`. It pollutes the global namespace. Use `std::` prefix.
2. You can't use `+` operator on C-strings. Use `std::string` instead (you are using C++, aren't you?).
3. Check for the number of arguments provided: if it's `0` then your program will crash.
4. Better return the value returned by `system()`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2) {
        std::cerr << "Specify a folder\n";
        return 1;
    }

    std::string command = "ls " + std::string(argv[1]); // Note the space after ls
    return system(command.c_str());
}
```

Comment: `std::string command = "ls " + argv[1];` is not valid...

Comment: @ChrisMM I've edited my answer. Now it works. Thanks!